# using visual studio 2010 code coverage on sources hosted on a network drive

Tags: visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, code-coverage

Does anybody knows how to use the code coverage feature of VS2010 when the solutons/project are hosted on a network drive.

I use Clear Case as source repository and all our project are hosted on a network drive (mapped to z:)
When I try to enable the code coverage feature during unit test, the test run hangs.
I've tried several settings, but in all cases, the test hangs or did not pass.

Is there a solution or a workaround?
I found in some post at MSDN that this code coverage is not supported on network drive, a case has been opened but never resolved.

Comment: perhaps a link to the post could be provided.

Comment: have you ensured all the permissions are ok? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdc263t0(VS.80).aspx

Comment: it's not a permission limiation but a non implemented feature in code coverage tools. We've implemented a solution using post build script (copy file to local isolated storage, instrumentation & monitor of DLL, run Unit test project, copy code coverage & test results on the network, remove file from local storage), it works, code coverage result can be opened